# Create pandas dataframe column using another dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

```
bg_d = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None, index_col=None, usecols="C:N", skiprows=23, nrows=8)
identifier = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None, index_col=None, header=None, usecols="B", skiprows=13, nrows=1)
```

This results in two dictionaries of dataframes (one dataframe per sheet in excel), something like this:

```
bg_d: {
Sheet1: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12,
Sheet2: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12,
Sheet3: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 }
# note - each column (1, 2,3 etc.) has my experimental numbers

identifier: {
Sheet1: Water Sample,
Sheet2: Glycerin,
Sheet3: Serum }
```

I want the final dataframe of each sheet to look like this:

```
Water Sample 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
Glycerin 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
Serum 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

I've tried this:

```
bg_sheets = []
for sheet, name in bg_d.items():
   for s, n in identifier.items():
      val = n.values[0][0]
      sheet["Plate"] = val
      bg_sheets.append(sheet)
```

But I get a string error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by `bg_d.items()` returning key and value, so the `sheet` is a string, not a dataframe. And you just need single loop. The code will be like this:

```
bg_sheets = []
for name,sheet  in bg_d.items():
    n = identifier.get(name)
    val = n.values[0][0]
    sheet["Plate"] = val
    bg_sheets.append(sheet)
```